# How do I change TOC location in wkhtmltopdf output?

Tags: xslt, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I need the TOC to be on the 3rd page. Apparently, if there is a way to control this, it has to be through the XSL stylesheet. All my search attempts didn't give me a clue though. Is it possible at all?

I can't use `cover` option since I need the header to show on both first and second pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I've found a way to do it using wkhtmltopdf 0.11. I've extracted the first two pages into a separate HTML document and then run it like this

```
wkhtmltopdf [options] page cover.html toc --xsl-style-sheet ... input_file.html out.pdf
```

Unfortunately it took a lot more effort than I expected, since I'm using it in a Rails application through wicked_pdf, and it doesn't play nice with the new options format, so I had to fork it and make the necessary changes as well.

The command line generated by wicked_pdf looks like this (long paths omitted):

```
"c:/program files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe"  
   --header-html "file:///path/to/header" --footer-html "file:///path/to/footer" 
   --margin-top 20 --margin-bottom 15 --margin-left 5 --margin-right 40    page "file:///path/to/cover/page" --disable-javascript  toc --xsl-style-sheet "path/to/style/sheet"  - -
```

Comment: Does that mean that in "..." you have your extracted pages? Would it be possible to see the actual command used? The "page" directive is not familiar to me. To me that reads like "put page cover.html and then toc and then input_file.html and print out.pdf", but I doubt that it's not like that is it? Good question and nicely found for the answer

Comment: I believe this notation for 'page' and 'toc' objects got introduced somewhere around v0.10. wkhtmltopdf puts those objects in the output in the order given in the command line. The ... is actually the path to the XSL sheet, sorry for not making this clear. I've added the CLI that wicked_pdf generates in my application.

Comment: to say it simple, you can have multiple *page* objects along with a *cover* and *toc* object. I used the same trick = instead of using a *cover* which  is difficult to set header/footers for, I use a single page as cover, then the toc, then the rest of my document, so `[page][toc][page]` vs `[cover][toc][page]`

Comment: @frequent Please suggest, how did you achieve this [page][toc][page] ? I mean when we load view using wkhtmltopdf it puts outline or toc on first page automatically, how can we add a page before toc ?

Comment: @ManojVerma - documentation says you can have multiple page objects. Just use this. https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Hi @
I am a Python developer, and I am beginner at using wkhtmltopdf, and currently I have a html being converted into a pdf. But I want to automatically include a table of contents. The documentation says I should put a file called toc.xsl into the param toc. But I am not familiar with .xsl files, so I am not sure what that file should contain. I looked online for examples, but I think they are a little beyond me. Can you please help guide me? Thanks!